# Updating dictionary with loop

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dict like so:

```
d = {'pens': (3, 0), 'cups': (2, 0), 'coins': (7, 0)}
```

I am trying to access the key to update the 2nd attirbute e.g.

```
for x,y,z in d.items():
    if x=='pens'
       z=5
```

Why does this not work? What is a solution that does?

Comment: You should try to avoid looping through `dict`s and use them appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z` is only temporarily bound to the value that you get from the second part of the tuple; it is not a reference back to the tuple itself. You have to find the tuple within the original dict, then update it (which is complicated by the fact that tuples are immutable). Try something like this:

```
for x, (y, z) in d.items():
    if x == 'pens':
        d[x] = (y, 5)
```

Comment: Should we be promoting looping through `dict`s (which takes `O(n)`), or making the most of their `O(1)` lookup?

Comment: @Aidenhjj I'm assuming that the poster's use case is more complicated than what was presented, and that it actually justifies looping through the whole dict, and that it was presented like this here for the purpose of minimizing extraneous details.

Comment: @user3030010 Quite correct. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
d = {'pens': (3, 0), 'cups': (2, 0), 'coins': (7, 0)}
if 'pens' in d:
    d['pens'] = (d['pens'][0], 5)
```

Comment: This doesn't include check whether `pens` actually exist in dictionary, and would cause `KeyError` if it isn't there.

Comment: @Fejs - you beat me to the post anyway, so I have upvoted yours.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your solution couldn't work is because tuples are immutable, which means there contents cannot be changed. There similar. constants in other language. Furthermore, `.items()`   returns a two tuple pair, so trying to unpack it with three variables should have raised an error.

With that said, You can make use of dictionary comprehension, and Python's ternary operator:

```
>>> d = {'pens': (3, 0), 'cups': (2, 0), 'coins': (7, 0)}
>>> d = {key: (val[0], 5) if key == 'pens' else val for key, val in d.items()}
>>> d
{'pens': (3, 5), 'cups': (2, 0), 'coins': (7, 0)}
>>>
```

Comment: This answer increments by 5 as opposed to setting the value to 5 as in the question.

Comment: @Aidenhjj Thanks. Realized my mistake. fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you cannot update a tuple(the values in the dictionary), as tuples are immutable so you will have to assign the key new tuple. Other thing wrong with this loop is the way tuple is unpacked. It should be like this

```
for x,(y,z) in d.items():
    if x=='pens':
       d[x] = (y, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because You're not changing it in dictionary.
You could do it this way:

```
if "pens" in d.keys():
    d["pens"] = (d["pens"][0], 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems here.

First, `items()` returns an iterable whose elements are 2-element tuples, with the first of each tuple being the key and the second being the value.

In your case, you need to unpack the "value" tuple further:

```
for x, value in d.items():
  y, z = value
```

Second, it looks like you are trying to update the dict with your new value ("5"), but you just have a copy of the element, and the value type itself is a tuple, which is immutable.  You can't change a single element of the tuple.  So you will have to replace the entire value tuple in the dict with a new tuple:

```
for x, value in d.items():
    y, z = value
    if x == 'pens':
        d[x]  = (y, 5)
```

Note that updating a dict or list while you are iterating over it can be a problem in some cases.  Be careful.